# Foreach só funciona se o array estiver dentro de colchetes

Tags: javascript, foreach

Esta acontecendo algo bem estranho, estou utilizando foreach para adicionar valores diretamente pela ID, só que o estranho e que a função só funciona se o array estiver dentro de um colchete.

```js
var elements1 = document.getElementsByClassName("rating1");
var array1 = ["9.0", "9.5", "7.1"];

for (var i = 0; i < elements1.length; i++) {
    elements1[i].innerHTML = array1[i];
}

var elements2 = document.getElementsByClassName("rating2");
var array2 = ("9.0", "9.5", "7.1");
for (var i = 0; i < elements2.length; i++) {
    elements2[i].innerHTML = array2[i];
}
```

```html
<h2>Aqui funciona perfeitamente</h2>
<div class="rating1"></div>
<div class="rating1"></div>
<div class="rating1"></div>
<br>
<h2>Aqui não funciona</h2>
<div class="rating2"></div>
<div class="rating2"></div>
<div class="rating2"></div>
```

Esse e apenas um exemplo do que esta acontecendo.

O problema e o seguinte, estou utilizando o [plugin do imdb](https://www.imdb.com/plugins) para capturar a qualificação dos filmes.

Quando faço a requisição o sistema me retorna os dados, acredito que seja em JSON, todas as qualificações que foram solicitadas vem juntas dentro de um value chamado "rating".

estou utilizando o mesmo código a acima, a unica coisa que muda e que estou usando o array que vem no valor "rating":

```
var array1 = rating;
```

Só que em vez de funcionar como no primeiro exemplo, por algum motivo fica igual o segundo exemplo.

Answer (score 5):

[image: problema.png]

Acho que essa imagem deixa bem claro o que está errado, né?

Seu segundo "array" na verdade não é um array.

Você deve estar confundindo com a sintaxe de tuplas do Python, que não existe em JS. No Javascript, arrays *são entre colchetes*.

Esse negócio com parêntesis que você quer que seja um array na verdade só avalia todas as expressões que você põe lá dentro separadas por `,` e retorna a última. Por isso seus itens na segunda lista são `7`, `.` e `1`: esses são os caracteres da sua string.

Answer (score 1):

Para usar um array sem colchete e como fizeste no exemplo onde nao funciona precisas usar o .push();

Mas este precisa de estar definido antes

```
var array2 = new Array();
array2.push("9.0");
array2.push("9.5");

console.log(array2);
//["9.0", "9.5"]
```

EDIT
Na verdade usar new Array(); é bom porque podes definir o tamanho do array

Ex: Array(5);

pois este tambem define o tamanho do mesmo na stack e pode prevenir erros do tipo stack overflow e aumentar a performance

`new Array (5)` na verdade não adicionará cinco itens indefinidos ao array. Simplesmente adiciona espaço para cinco itens.

Em contrepartida instanciar um Array dessa maneira torna difícil confiar em array.length para cálculos.

EDIT 2

Se estiveres a recuperar um objeto JSON podes usar o `JSON.parse();`

```
var array2 = JSON.parse(objeto_json);
```

E em seguida podes iterar pela tua array com um `foreach` ou com um `for`
Eu aconselho o for pois um foreach sera mais lento, este tem que verificar bastante coisa antes de passar a proxima propriedade/valor;

Comment: Isso lança um `TypeError: array2 is undefined` para mim, tem certeza de que está correto? Parece muito estranho também...

Comment: Certo, corrigi agora faltava instanciar o array

Comment: realmente funciona do jeito que você falou, mas somente utilizando os dados manualment e no console.log, utilizando os dados que vem da requisição em JSON não funciona, só aparece undefined.

Comment: esses dados que vem da requisição talvez sejam object, por isso não esta funcionando, mas sou leigo quanto ao js.

Comment: precisa fazer um parse com JSON.parse(objeto_json)